# Remove all occurrences of text within string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Say I had a string in JavaScript that looked like this:

```
var str = "Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop1=1&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop1=2&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop1=3&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop1=4&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00"
```

and wanted it to look like this:

```
var str = "Something%5B0%5D.Prop1=1&Something%5B0%5D.Prop2=False&Something%5B0%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Something%5B1%5D.Prop1=2&Something%5B1%5D.Prop2=False&Something%5B1%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Something%5B2%5D.Prop1=3&Something%5B2%5D.Prop2=False&Something%5B2%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Something%5B3%5D.Prop1=4&Something%5B3%5D.Prop2=False&Something%5B3%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00"
```

i.e. remove all of the Item%5BX%5D. parts

How would I go about doing this? I thought of using something like:

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf('Something'), str.length);
```

but obviously that only removes the first occurrence.

Also the number in-between the %5B and %5D could be anything, not necessarily 9.

This seems like something that should be simple but for some reason I'm stumped. I found a few similarish things on SO but nothing that handled all the above criteria.

Comment: use `str.replace('/Item%5BX%5D/g','')`;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regular expression :

```
str = str.replace(/Item[^.]+\./g, '');
```

or if you want something more precise because you'd want to keep `Item%6B3%4D` :

```
str = str.replace(/Item%5B.%5D\./g, '');
```

Comment: Huzzah! Perfect, I can't say I'm particularly good with this regex malarky, but that's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = str.replace('Item%5B9%5D', '');
```

EDIT: Missed the part where `9` in the string could be any number. You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/Item%5B\d%5D\./g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite do the trick, as it won't always be the number 9 and I won't necessarily know what the number is - sorry if that wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using a regular expression where complex "needle" escaping is required:

```
var str =  "something complex full of http://, 'quotes' and more keep1 something complex full of http://, 'quotes' and more keep2 something complex full of http://, 'quotes' and more keep3"
var needle = "something complex full of http://, 'quotes' and more";
 while( str.indexOf(needle) != '-1')
 str = str.replace(needle,"");
 document.write(str);
```

Outputs:
keep1 keep2 keep3

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
str = str.replace(/Item%5B\d%5D\./g,'');
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nRv8u/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/Item%5B[^.]*%5D./g, '');
```

This assumes that you can have anything of any length between `%5B` and `%5D`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cdunh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()` & `join()` method

```js
var str = "Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop1=1&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B0%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop1=2&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B1%5D.Prop3=10%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop1=3&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B2%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop1=4&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop2=False&Item%5B9%5D.Something%5B3%5D.Prop3=29%2F04%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00";
console.log(str.split(/Item%5B\d%5D\./g).join(''));
```